# DXA 1.6 disable CWD Context

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

Is it possible to disable CWD Context?, in our implementation we don't really need any of the CWD_* libraries since Tridion won't be used for device detection and CWD_* are adding an unnecessary load.

Note: We also won't be using ADF

Comment: Do you use 2013SP1 version of SDL Web 8?

Comment: I am using 2013sp1

Answer (score 2):

No matter which version of Tridion/SDL Web you are using, you can just exclude CWD dependencies if they're coming transitively. 
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management

Comment: You cannot really exclude the dependencies, I tried that before and got spring initialization errors. I was looking for a dxa.properties solution where we can indicate that we don't need cwd